# Serial port communication

Tags: communication, serial-bus

I have transmitted the data from a PC to other devices using a serial port cable. In that case I was using windows 7 32 bit os. But when I tried it with 64 bit os I am not able to transmit it. Is there a way to transmit the data from a PC with windows 7, 64bit is?

Comment: Why are you not able to transmit data? Can you be more specific?

Comment: serial works fine with 64 bit windows, subject to the same software problems that 32 bit windows has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PC Serial port is a pretty standard thing (if you actually have one).  Unless you are talking with off-beat devices that are "TTL RS-232".

The underlying OS doesn't matter from DOS to Plan9 to Windows to Unix... A serial port is a serial port.
More likely, is that you have different settings in your terminal program.  The program that you use for serial communications has to set up the port in a certain way for various devices.  You need to have the correct baud rate, the correct number of bits per byte, the correct number of stop bits, and the correct flow control.  If any of those are set wrong, you generally can't communicate, or will only see garbage characters.

Even decent USB to Serial adapters follow all of the normal rules, and are still addressed the same by all communications software that I know of.

Comment: Thanks u and when I try it with a windows 7 with 32 bit I get the communication done. If the terminal settings is different I don't think so that  the communication will take place. And I use a VB form to send and receive the data.

Comment: It is possible your application is trying to use the wrong com port..

Comment: Hi thanks. I got it sorted when using VB and Serial port cable the VB will only accept comport from 1 to 5, and not anything other than that. U need to set the comp port between 1 and 5